# Are Visual Studio's Web Load & Performance Testing tools available in the Enterprise edition for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I'm checking Microsoft's docs, but I cannot find any clear indication that the same tools Visual Studio Enterprises offers on Windows for Web Load & Performance Testing are available as well on the Mac edition. Has anyone ever used them on Mac?

It's also not clear to me if anything changes on the Mac installation once I sign-in with an Enterprise subscription. The installer seems to be the same for all editions. Do additional tools become available, or is it just a matter o licensing?

Answer (score 0):

Additional tools *do* become available in Microsoft's Visual Studio for Mac with the Enterprise license, one of which *is* a Profiler - but it is not the same tool as the one for Visual Studio on Windows.

The Web Load tool, however, does not exist for Mac.

Comment: Thanks for that. Have you ever found any feature comparison matrix on any Microsoft page that makes it clear what features are available in VS for mac, and what features are not?